# Add list items to datagridview and database table

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox

I have a listbox with a list of values (listbox name = RoleName).  Based on selections in the listbox, those values get added to the RoleName table.  However, when I try adding, it adds the right number of rows, but the same value (the first value) all the way down.  label1.Text shows the correct UserID at the top.  Is something wrong with my loop?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmdAdd = new SqlCommand("insert into Josh_REL_Table (UserID, RoleName) Values (@UserID , @RoleName)", con);
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            con.Open();
            cmdAdd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmdAdd.Parameters.Add("@RoleName", SqlDbType.VarChar);

            foreach (var i in RoleName.SelectedIndices)
            {
                cmdAdd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = label1.Text;
                cmdAdd.Parameters["@RoleName"].Value = RoleName.SelectedItem;
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving SelectedItem instead of every item from loop. CHeck below comment

```
foreach (var currentItem in RoleName.SelectedItems)
            {
                cmdAdd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = label1.Text;
                cmdAdd.Parameters["@RoleName"].Value = currentItem // Or i in your code. 
//RoleName.SelectedItem; selected item is always same.
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you.  All I changed from that was from RoleName.SelectedIndices to RoleName.SelectedItems since I missed that

Comment: Cool, I edited the code to say SelectedItems as well.